# Sending a file via POST using Django using Javascript instead of HTML Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, file, upload

I have a PDF file saved in a variable 'report.'

I am using Django and want to pass it to a function in my views.py file using POST --

```
@xframe_options_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def process_report(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
         report_file = request.FILES['docfile']
         ....
         return response
```

How can I send a ajax POST request with this file? The filetype is a PDF.

I was using an HTML form to do this before, but I wanted to style the form upload using javascript. I tried styling the button using javascript (changing colors and text depending on file type uploaded), but the file was no longer being able to be passed through the POST request. Now I just have the file saved in a javascript variable, and am trying to just pass it via POST without using form. I understand it's impossible to prepopulate a form with a file.

My old code:

```
<form id="boring" action="{% url "process_report" %}" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }                
        {{ form.docfile.errors }}
        {{ form.docfile }}

    </form>
```

What I have been trying to do with ajax

```
var formdata = new FormData(report);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'process_report',
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType : 'application/pdf',
      data: {
                'content': 'formdata',
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
             }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540723/django-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. I ultimately decided to use xhr instead of ajax, but here is the answer for ajax.

First, I was setting up form data incorrectly, as it should be down as

```
// Set up form data
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("docfile", report)
```

Second, the ajax had to be updated

```
// Pass the form to views via POST
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url "process_report" %}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false, // essential
    contentType: false, // essential, application/pdf doesn't work. 
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

    // If sucess, download file
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
          console.log(data;
    }
});
```